# Using $this when not in object context. ERROR

Tags: php

```
<?

class Flip 
{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function flips()
    {
        $flips = array();

        $result = $this->db->Select()->Get('flips');
        if($result)
        {
            foreach ($result as $value) 
            {
                $flips[] = $value;
            }
            return $flips;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function flipComment($id)
    {
        return $this->db->Select()->Where('id', $id)->Get('comments');
    }

}
```

> Fatal error: Using `$this` when not in object context.

Any ideas how to fix?  I don't want to recall class Database for each function.  I need to be able to use `$this->db`

Comment: Can you post a full class declaration? $this is used inside the class declaration. Otherwise you need to use a instance name.

Comment: Can you please show the full error message , which line does this error occurs ?

Comment: The code you have pasted thus far is valid.  You need to show the full error message including line number, and make sure you are copy/pasting exactly your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$this` because the functions are not part of a class.

```
    Class MyClass {
        private $db;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = new Database();
        }

        public function comment()
        {
            $this->__construct();

            return $this->db->Select()->Get('comments');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable static and in the constructor you can see if it's already set. Then you will only have to open the connection once and every time you call `Flip` it will be able to use that connection.

```
class Flip
{
    private static $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$db))
            self::$db = new Database();
    }

    function comment()
    {
        return self::$db->Select()->Get('comments');
    }
}
```

More on the [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: I don't wanna recall the class Database.

Comment: what do you mean by recall? do you mean you don't want to make a new connection to the database?

Comment: I wrote an interpreter database class that is crafts my query and I would like to save memory by only needing to call it once inserted of each function requiring the class

Comment: Call to a member function Select() on a non-object

Comment: Did you fix my typo `$b->` should be `$db->`. I will edit that in my answer